# Apache Camel Choice(): Do Nothing

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel

I have made an application using Apache Camel that integrates well with AWS S3. Here is the code:

```
Predicate newFilePred = header(NEW_FILE_RECEIVED_HEADER).isEqualTo(SUCCESS);
from(incomingEndpoint)
        .process((exchange) -> {
            logger.info("Checking S3 bucket.");
            Date newFileUploadDate = (Date) exchange.getIn().getHeaders().get("CamelAwsS3LastModified");
            if (fileIsNew(newFileUploadDate))
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(NEW_FILE_RECEIVED_HEADER, SUCCESS);
            } else {
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(NEW_FILE_RECEIVED_HEADER, FAILURE);
            }
        })
        .choice()
            .when(newFilePred)
            .to(outgoingEndpoint)
        .endChoice()
        .end();
```

The application works well, but it throws a really annoying warning seen below:

```
Camel Thread #1 - aws-s3://mybucket] | c.a.s.s.i.S3AbortableInputStream Not all bytes were read from the
S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. 
Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use. request_id=
```

I know the problem is that I dont direct the output of the file anywhere if the header "NEW_FILE_RECEIVED_HEADER" is set to failure. This is by design because I do not want to download the file in this case. Is there anyway to tell Camel to abort the connection properly after I have identified the file as "unwanted"? I could create another camel route directly to a "trash" directory, but these would be useless cycles.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would not think so as you can see from the text from AWS itself that says you need to drain the stream. I assume you cannot know ahead of time if you want to skip this file, so you cannot on the GET call limit the number of bytes.

Comment: If this is the case, then I believe it would be nice to suppress this warning in the event of an intentional cancellation. Would you see this as worthy enough for an enhancement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For lack of a better solution, I managed to mute these messages by implementing a garbage/failure route that finishes the http get/input stream from S3.

If someone comes up with a better method or a different approach entirely, please feel free to "beat" this answer. The underlying rule that was discovered is that a finished route (A -> B) is required or a warning will be thrown. The warnings are harmless unless you view a polluted log file like I do.

Finished route conditionals look like this:

```
.choice()
   .when(newFilePred)
      .to(successfulOutgoingEndpoint)
   .otherwise()
      .to(failureOutgoingEndpoint);
```